# can we remove redis url from Sidekiq dahsboard?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

In the Sidekiq dashboard, is there any option to modify the default Sidekiq dashboard to hide Redis URL?

I tried hiding them but not getting them right. I need to figure out if there are any config settings to make changes in the Sidekiq dashboard.
@Mike Perham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monkeypatch `Sidekiq::WebHelpers#redis_url` to return whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would choose one of these 2 options:

**Fork and modify Sidekiq:** You can fork the Sidekiq repository and make the necessary changes to the dashboard code to remove the Redis URL display. This would require Ruby and Rails development knowledge. Once you have made the modifications, you can use your customized version of Sidekiq in your project.

or

**Use a reverse proxy:** Instead of modifying Sidekiq directly, you can set up a reverse proxy server (e.g., Nginx) in front of Sidekiq. The reverse proxy can be configured to intercept requests to the Sidekiq dashboard and modify the response by removing the Redis URL before it reaches the client's browser. This approach allows you to customize the dashboard without modifying the Sidekiq codebase directly.

**REPLY EDIT:**

So lets Modifying Sidekiq directly:
Fork the Sidekiq repository on GitHub: Visit the Sidekiq repository (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) and click on the "Fork" button in the top right corner to create a copy of the repository under your GitHub account.

Clone your forked repository to your local machine:

```
git clone https://github.com/your-username/sidekiq.git
```

Make the necessary modifications: Navigate to the **web/views** folder in the cloned repository. You can modify the relevant view files (**e.g., app/views/sidekiq/dashboard.erb)** to remove the Redis URL display. Save your changes.

Build and install the modified version: Follow the instructions provided in the Sidekiq repository's README file to build and install your modified version of Sidekiq.

**When Using a reverse proxy method:**
First Set up a reverse proxy server: Install and configure a reverse proxy server such as Nginx or Apache. Consult the documentation of the chosen server for detailed instructions on installation and configuration.

Configure the reverse proxy: In the reverse proxy server's configuration file, add a location block or virtual host configuration for the Sidekiq dashboard endpoint. Within this block, use a combination of rewrite rules and proxy settings to modify the Sidekiq dashboard response and remove the Redis URL.

I found this example:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your-domain.com;

    location /sidekiq {
        rewrite ^/sidekiq(/.*)$ $1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # Assuming Sidekiq is running on port 3000
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        # Add additional proxy settings as needed
    }

    # Add other server configuration as needed
}
```

In this case  the rewrite directive removes the **/sidekiq** prefix from the URL, and the **proxy_pass** directive proxies the request to the Sidekiq server.

Restart the reverse proxy server: After making the configuration changes, restart the reverse proxy server to apply the modifications.

With this configuration, the reverse proxy intercepts requests to the Sidekiq dashboard and modifies the response before it reaches the client's browser, effectively removing the Redis URL from the displayed content.

Make sure that you adjust the configuration based on your specific environment and requirements.

Comment: Thanks @Magico.
Could you please share any referrence for both the cases Magico. And I tried making changes in the web/views folder from the Sidekiq library but those changes are not seen in the application as I have mounted Sidekiq.
Is there any possibility to make the URL removed with web server config changes?

Comment: @SaranRaajBaskaran I did not know how to write such a long answer to the comment reply so I just edited original answer and placed reply there :)

Comment: Thanks for your time @Magico.
Will use them upon the requirement.